# Install nodejs in Linux Mint. Error (Broken pipe)

Tags: node.js, linux-mint, broken-pipe

I tried installing every version. I removed and installed it multiple times

**This is the error.
**
wget -qO- https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | bash -
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/25,4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 121 MB of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 585005 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../nodejs_14.21.3-deb-1nodesource1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nodejs (14.21.3-deb-1nodesource1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nodejs_14.21.3-deb-1nodesource1_a
md64.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite '/usr/include/node/common.gypi', which is also in package libnode-d
ev 12.22.9~dfsg-1ubuntu3wget -qO- https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | bash -
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/nodejs_14.21.3-deb-1nodesource1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@NewEpoka:/home/newepokadevs#

I had version 12.2 but i needed to upgrade it to version 14+.

Now Im getting error code (1)